# How to use different file format for apk?

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I want to store local android applications on local android repository (e.g. using fdroid) using different format (for example compressed in bzip2 -- MyApp.bz).

Can I change fdroid server to send bzip2 files to fdroid android "play store" app and then decompress it, tar it
(Or to keep it in uncompressed format) and rename as apk before handling it to the android package manager to be able do this? Will it still being able to install app with android package manager?

From what I understand not all apk files are compressed with zip, so package manager should understand tared file with renamed extension?

Answer (score 1):

That´s not possible the only permitted format is the `Android Application Package` (`.APK`) that is compressed as `.ZIP`

Comment: Not all apks are compressed, right? By tar I simply mean not compressed.

Comment: The .apk file format is already a compression format, so all the .apk´s are compressed read more: http://www.compressfilesandroid.com/apk.html

Comment: It would be possible to manually make a valid APK that was not ZIP-compressed. The ZIP format allows for uncompressed entries.